# splatmap textures not applying in build in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, terrain

im procedurally creating my heightmaps and declaring my terrain in the scripts

in the unity editor, my splatmaps work perfectly, however when i build my terrain is just plain black.

is there a setting that i may have missed when building that is required to make the splats work ?.

editor 
http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/31838-untitle2d.png

build 
http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/31839-untitled.png

i load them in using code with

```
SplatPrototype[] terrainTexture = new SplatPrototype[4]; 
        terrainTexture[0] = new SplatPrototype(); 
        terrainTexture[0].texture = (Texture2D)Resources.Load("stone");
        terrainTexture[1] = new SplatPrototype(); 
        terrainTexture[1].texture = (Texture2D)Resources.Load("sand");
        terrainTexture[2] = new SplatPrototype(); 
        terrainTexture[2].texture = (Texture2D)Resources.Load("grass");
        terrainTexture[3] = new SplatPrototype(); 
        terrainTexture[3].texture = (Texture2D)Resources.Load("snow");
```

edit 
i attempted adding the textures to the code as variables draged in rather than using resource.load, also didnt work

edit
i found a work around which makes it work, but its unfortunate that i coudnt find a proper solution.
can anyone see something that could be the cause of the issue

http://
answers.unity3d.com/questions/171150/terrain-basemap-texture-through-code.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include an extra shader in your build. Go to edit -> project settings -> graphics. In the inspector increase the size. In the new slot select Nature/Terrain/Diffuse.

The reason you need to do this is that Unity will search for any assets that are referenced in the scene to decide what to include in the build and what to leave out. Since your terrain is built procedurally there is no terrain object and no terrain material present, and the required shader is not included. By following the above steps you basically tell Unity to include it anyway because you know you are going to need it.

Answer (score 0):

I would add in a few things to the above answer:

1. There is a prototypes refresh, called TerrainData.RefreshPrototypes() that is supposed to refresh all available prototypes, including the detail textures and trees. Since the ground textures are part of the prototypes listing, this will help unity update the new textures for the terrain. (And, it also works inside of the Editor.)
2. Also, others have found that when they change the textures' data (ie, changing the pixel data) that it causes unity to update the materials used for the terrain. They made a blank terrain, assigned blank base textures to it, and then at runtime loaded up the height map, splat maps, and overwrote the textures. This caused unity to display the newly created terrains.

I hope that this helps out some, as most of the terrain asset is a highly undocumented area (and rather dysfunctional, too)... Good Luck!